# html Javascript EXIF from image

Tags: javascript, html, gps, exif

(sorry for my bad english) i have donwload a demo from here:

https://github.com/bennoleslie/jsjpegmeta

In this good demo, you have to select one file using a form and after submit the same page show you all EXIF information (also create link to Google maps).

I need to modify only this html page (because i dont know javascript) so that when i call it, read the image directly from a folder (es: C:\test.jpg) instead using the form imput to select the file. if it is possible.

This is the html page where you select the image (with exif data):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="dropbox" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JsJpegMeta Demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jpegmeta.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>JsJpegMeta Demo</h1>
  <form id="form" action="javascript:void(0)">
    <p>Choose JPEG file: <input id="fileWidget" type="file"></p>
  </form>
  <img id="img" height="100" alt="Image preview" src="">
  <div id="status"></div>
</body>
```

Thanks to those who will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automatically select a file on a webpage. That would be a HUGE security issue. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#file-select

JavaScript is very restricted to protect users. If you don't need this on a webpage, you should find an EXIF parser in another language

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the clear reply. One last thing I'll let lose after that.

If I have already prepared the file path, there is a way to pass the file path and do the submit pressing a key? so as to avoid at least go and look on the disk and select it?

Basically I do a page (ASP Classic) that shows the photos and I have to give a chance to the user (by pressing "our" button) to see the exif information.
...This demo does exactly what I need.